# texturepacker rounded border

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

I created a rounded rectangle on illustrator and export in to png , then added this image to texturepacker and import to cocos2d here is my rectangle, 
Have you any idea why there are white pixels on the corner.

Here is image https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9018754/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-31%20at%2023.28.52.png

Comment: Did you try the reduce border artifacts option?

Comment: yes, interesting but here is the visual if i check reduce border artifacts
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9018754/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-01%20at%2000.18.41.png

Comment: and here is my setting in texturepacker
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9018754/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-01%20at%2000.22.42.png

Answer (score 0):

Might be that the image was written as png8 with blending towards a white background in Illustrator.
Can you also post the png you created from Illustrator?

-- update --

The image looks fine. I think we can rule out problems with exporting the image.

In your settings "Premultiply Alpha" is off. When importing the image into cocos2d, did you enabled premultipled alpha?
Both values must be matching. Otherwise you will get some strange behaviour.

If it's on in TexturePacker and off in cocos2d you get black outlines.
If it's off in TexturePacker and on in cocos2d you get white outlines.

So: Try enabling it in TexturePacker.

Comment: i saved as PNG-24 and transparent here is png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9018754/grid5.png

Comment: The image seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  Premultiply Alpha solved my problem

Changing ccConfig.h to

`#ifndef CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL`
`#define CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL 1`
`#endif`

and setting premultiply alpha + exclude 1  solved my problem ,

It is written in the comment line

**

` **If enabled, the texture coordinates will be calculated by using this formula:

   - texCoord.left = (rect.origin.x*2+1) / (texture.wide*2);

   - texCoord.right = texCoord.left + (rect.size.width*2-2)/(texture.wide*2);

 The same for bottom and top.

 This formula prevents artifacts by using 99% of the texture.

 The "correct" way to prevent artifacts is by using the spritesheet-artifact-fixer.py or a similar tool.

 Affected nodes:

    - CCSprite / CCSpriteBatchNode and subclasses: CCLabelBMFont, CCTMXLayer

    - CCLabelAtlas

    - CCParticleSystemQuad

    - CCTileMap

 To enabled set it to 1. Disabled by default.**
**

I couldnt figure out what is going on at the moment  but  I will check code deeper ,

Thank you Andreas Löw